# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: System unavailable - due to inability to connect to the database?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I get the following error message when trying to access our online giving site, on which no changes were made since Dec 16 (we are Dec 28) - any help is appreciated considering that this is the time of the year we receive most donations!:

UPDATE: It looks like our database is down - could this be related to the error I am getting below?

---

```
HTTP Status 500 -
type Exception report message

description The server encountered an internal error () 
that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: System unavailable.
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:500)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
edu.columbia.udar.giving.EntryPoint.doBeforeProcessing(EntryPoint.java:59)
edu.columbia.udar.giving.EntryPoint.doFilter(EntryPoint.java:140)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: System unavailable.
edu.columbia.udar.giving.FundLoader.processRequest(FundLoader.java:84)
edu.columbia.udar.giving.FundLoader.doGet(FundLoader.java:102)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:965)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:186)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:371)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
edu.columbia.udar.giving.EntryPoint.doBeforeProcessing(EntryPoint.java:59)
edu.columbia.udar.giving.EntryPoint.doFilter(EntryPoint.java:140)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.34 logs.
```

---

I restarted Apache, looked at server and Tomcat logs but can't find anything obvious. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It was due to our Oracle database being down.